# How to convey to someone that food is losing heat?

Tags: american-english, phrase-requests

The story is that I want someone to come earlier to the dining table as food is hot now but in ten minutes it would not be.

How in American English can I say to someone to come early, as food on the table is getting cold or losing heat?

Comment: "Hurry up, your food has a negative temperature gradient."

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Your dinner is getting cold* will be quite acceptable I think. Dunno if there are any idiomatic synonyms though.

Comment: +1 I answered the same but deleted when I saw you beat me by 14 seconds. Note that the name of any meal may be substituted for "dinner" in this timeless bit of nagging heard from moms everywhere. I'd bet moms have a version of this in all languages. "The Sisterhood of the Traveling Rants" or something like that ...

Comment: @Robusto It was first that popped to mind. Dunno why, but this phrase is associated with dinner to me. Probably, I was too hungry after good night sleep to be late for breakfast :)

Comment: First thing that popped into my mind, too. My guess is that's it tends to be associated with dinner because that's the meal that is most likely to be served hot.

Answer (score 19):

*Get it while it's hot* is an alternative to *your dinner's getting cold*.

Comment: @Fumble: Philoto's answer was posted an hour earlier, not later

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: Oh. Well if you say so I guess that must be it. They both say "5 hours ago" now. I meant no disrespect to Philoto - I must have just misinterpreted what I saw earlier, which is why the upvotes struck me as really odd. In the end, one hopes the *best* answer comes out on top, regardless of when it was posted.

Comment: @Fumble: If you wait about 25 minutes, you'll see @Philato's answer listed as *"6 hours ago"* :)

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: It already has. And if I wait another day @horatio's will prolly have the most votes! :)